# NUMBER(p, s) Data Type: Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

So, let me start by saying I have had a hard time finding any documentation about this online - hence I am asking, here. I am having to manually calculate the size of a row in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 here at work (I know this can be done via a query; however, do to some hardware issues, it is not presently possible). Either way, I figured this question might help others in the long run:

Within the database that I am working, there are a number of columns with data type `NUMBER()` - some of which have set the precision and scale for the number. Now, I *do* know that precision affects size; however, here is the question: what is the range for the disk size of data type `NUMBER` in SQL Server in **bytes** (any measurement is fine, actually).

Some documentation will provide the possible ranges of sizes and the corresponding disk size. If you know of any documentation for this data type, please feel free to post.

OBSERVATION:

I have found documentation for type `NUMERIC`. Is that the same - or a different version of - `NUMBER`?

Comment: Custom data type maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean [NUMERMIC(p,s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah, oddly enough it isn't numeric. I even asked a guy - one of the lead developers - what the NUMBER(argument) type was and he said he had no idea. So, I just treated it like a DECIMAL(p,s) hoping the original designer was intending some similarity between the two. The numbers I came up with didn't fluctuate much in either direction either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew has mentioned it is a User Defined Type NUMBER since there is no default data type with name as `NUMBER` in sql server. And no one here can tell you what characteristics this Data type has.

You can execute the below query to find out what all the characteristics of this User defined Data type.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.types
WHERE is_user_defined = 1 
AND name = 'NUMBER'
```

Comment: Thank you! I am relatively new to SQL Server (and SQL in general), so I am learning my way around it in the throes of things - so to speak.

Comment: Not a problem glad to help :)